# Regex to prevent certain phone area codes

Tags: regex, angular

I'm trying to prevent users from typing a phone number that starts with area code 555.

Below is my phone regex.  How can I ensure the first 3 are not 555?

I thought about stopping numbers 5 for each, but it would have to be 555 consecutive.  Can it be done in one regex or do I need 2?

pattern="^(+0?1\s)?(?\d{3})?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$"

Comment: Your pattern's syntax looks off - you can't repeat a `(` (start-of-group) with `+`, and `(?\d...`isn't valid either, if you were trying to use a non-capturing group, the syntax for that is `(?:` (won't work without a colon)

Comment: Thanks.  Not sure I get what you mean.  Do you mean something like this?  This below still let's 555's through  ^(\+0?1\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?(?:!555)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$

Comment: Before even considering the `555` issue, you need proper syntax for your pattern first (both the one in the question and the one you just posted are invalid, and will throw errors) - just plug the pattern into regex101 or some other tester, and fix the errors

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Worked it out on regex101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using negative lookahead?

`pattern="^(?!555)[\d\s-]+"`

This looks for strings that contain digits, whitespaces and dashes, with the condition that it doesn't start with 555.

Test it out here: https://regex101.com/r/aVrZEl/1

Comment: This worked: ^(?!555)(\+0?1\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$